# Take a picture to External Storage <Gallery in smartphone>

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-camera, android-external-storage

I can't take a picture with camera and it isn't saved in the External directory and show in imageView.

At activity_main: Have button for take a picture, imageView for display image.

At AndroidManifest.xml:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

```
class MainActivity{    
      private Uri mImgFileUri;
       void onCreate(){ ...

        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                imageCapture();
            }
        });

    }

    private void imageCapture() {
        File extDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);

        File myPicDir = new File(extDir.getAbsolutePath()+"/MyPictures");
        if(!myPicDir.exists()){
            myPicDir.mkdirs();
        }
        Date dt = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyMMdd-HHmmss");

        String fileName = dateFormat.format(dt)+".jpg";
        File imgFile = new File(myPicDir+"/"+fileName);
        mImgFileUri = Uri.fromFile(imgFile);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,mImgFileUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent,555);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == 555 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            String path = mImgFileUri.getPath();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

Got this error

```
Error :

Process: com.example.cameraimagecapture, PID: 22554
    android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/MyPictures/20190630-165910.jpg exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
...MainActivity.imageCapture(MainActivity.java:57) >> startActivityForResult(intent,555);
...MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:23) >> class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {} 
...MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:36) >> imageCapture();
```

Comment: I just edited my code for precise language. I hope My answer works for you.

Comment: Could you please İf my answer works for you. Do you accept my answer as True?

Answer (score 0):

For putting the image to screen.

```
@Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


            if (resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED) {
                if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
                    Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
                }


            }
    }
```

Use the screenshot for getting save the photo to external storage :

1)Configure your layout in the activity. Example: RelativeLayout

```
RelativeLayout RelativeLayout;

 RelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout);
```

2)Detect your view in Bitmap Format like this code.

```
 private Bitmap getscreenshot(View view) {
        View v = view;
        v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());
        return bitmap;
    }
```

3)Set this code for saving your image.

```
private void SaveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {

        String root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();
        File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");
        myDir.mkdirs();
        Random generator = new Random();

        int n = 10000;
        n = generator.nextInt(n);
        String fname = "Image-" + n + ".jpg";
        File file = new File(myDir, fname);
        if (file.exists()) file.delete();
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            // sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
            //     Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
            out.flush();
            out.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[]{file.toString()}, null,
                new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                        Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                        Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                    }
                });
    }
```

4)Lastly, Use all of these codes to reach your intent :

```
 Bitmap screenshota = getscreenshot(RelativeLayout);
     SaveImage(screenshota);
```